# Android Studio Not Uploading Java File to my Repository(BitBucket)

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control, repository, bitbucket

I followed video tutorial on how to upload a file from android studio to bitbucket.

My problem is Java Files is not uploading in my repository.

```
  *.iml
   *.class
 .gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

This is my .gitignore.
This is my first time using this.

Answer (score 2):

this is the method i use for every project that use bitbucket:

go to terminal (android studio)

1. git init
2. git add --all
3. git commit -m "your message"

then go to bitbucket and create new repository then choose "I have an existing project" ...

Now you can use push/update

Comment: I don't understand #3?. sorry im new.

Comment: step 3 just write: git commit -m "any text here"